# How to read large files in C++ with mixed text and binary

Tags: c++, encryption, text-files, binaryfiles, large-files

I need to read a large file of either text, binary, or combination, such as a JPEG file, encrypt it, and write it to a file. At some later time I will need to read the encrypted data, and decrypt it. 
The end goal is to verify that the decrypted data matches the original data. 
My problem is that with large files greater than 1Meg, I don't want to read and write character by character. I am targeting this code for a phone and I/O will cause too long a delay for the user. 
With a pure text file, using fread() and fwrite() convert the data to binary, and the result is different than the original. With a jpeg image, it appears that there is some textual content mixed in with the binary data. 
Is there a way to efficiently read in an arbitrary type of file and write it back in the original format? 
Or is character by character the only option? 
Or am I still out of luck?

Comment: Why does it matter what the contents of the file are? Just use an algorithm that works on blocks of raw bytes ("binary mode").

Comment: Break it down into smaller tasks. Post what you've tried.

Comment: "*With a pure text file, using fread() and fwrite() convert the data to binary, and I cannot compare the end result with the original.*" I don't follow. Why can't you compare the end result with the original? You could use, for example, `memcmp` or `std::vector<unsigned char>::operator=`, or any other comparison mechanism you like.

Comment: C++ allows buffered file reading, so you are not sacrificing much speed by reading bytes.  Just make sure that your file is buffered when you open it for reading.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante  You are correct. It turns out that the buffers for the plain and cipher text were swapped in the decrypt function. Binary is working just fine. Thanks to all!

Comment: @David Schwartz Sorry, I meant that the end result did not match the original. I've modified the description, but I am also closing this since the root issue was a buffer swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging it turned out that the decrypt function had the plain text and cipher text buffers assigned backwards. After swapping the buffer assignments, the decrypted results matched the original data. I originally thought that maybe reading the text as binary and then rewriting as binary would not appear as text, but I was wrong. 
Reading the entire file as binary works just fine.